# Diferença de character e charset

Tags: mysql, sql, codificação-de-caracteres

Estou pegando algumas coisas em SQL, e as vezes me deparo com `CHARSET` e `CHARACTER`

Por exemplo:

```
create database teste 
default character set utf8;
```

E agora, criando uma tabela:

```
create table teste (
   teste varchar(30)
) DEFAULT CHARSET utf8;
```

Podem explicar por gentileza?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A primeira tem duas palavras, a segunda tem apenas uma :)

Sério não há diferença semântica, só sintática.